# Facebook webhook not being called

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

We have setup a webhook in facebook for our application in the app-portal and we are able to get call backs from the testpage in facebook to our web-hook-endpoint (USING WEB-API MVC 5).

However, when we try to call the webhook live, via our facebook user (capture user like-events) that has the application installed, the webhook doesnt get called. What are we doing wrong.

Do we need to setup some premission or register the application somehow or why doesn't it work?

Comment: Of course your app needs permission from the user to read their likes ...

Comment: Once we got the access_token and having the consent from the user to read their likes, how do we use the access token to setup the subscription on the user likes?

Comment: Those two issues are not directly related. You subscribe to updates for certain fields of the user object simply as the documentation describes. You will then get updates for those users that have logged in to your app and granted it the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Still not able to solve this. We are able to get the callbacks from the testpage but not from the real user activities. I.E likes on images or posts.  We initially created our own backend but we have also tried  this example. (https://github.com/EtienneCoumont/FacebookWebHooks). In the readme of this example there is a section describing page subscribtion but we are intrested in user subscribtion. We also have the access_token with the consent for the user_like scope. I guess we need to setup the subscribtion for the user object using the access token? How do we make that call to the api?

Comment: For updates on user objects, you subscribe your app as described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks, using the app access token. The user access token does not get involved at this point; you will get updates for _all_ users that have granted your app the necessary permissions that allow it access to the data.

Comment: Ok, but the problem remains that our webhook is not being called....when we trigger it through the testpage everything works fine....

Comment: WE just realized that likes connected to certain pages does indeed trigger the webhook....But we would also like to subscribe to likes connected to posts, images etc....is that not possible?

Comment: I think you need to subscribe to `feed` for that one ... a new reaction on a post is considered an “update” of that post.

Comment: We subscribed to "feed" aswell but we fail to get any updates regardless if we post something new on our feed, or if we/someone likes the new post

Comment: I have un unpublished page. I am getting the callback for a like, unlike and comment on a post. I am getting a like on the page. What I'm not getting are actions on an event (going, interested) and when I unlike the page.

Comment: Is there any chance that I can see the source-code behind that? I have no clue why we are not able to achieve this....